# Unable to extract data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The array is received from the facebook api and i am not able to extract the likes array from the array,Please help me

```
  [data] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [message] => Hello
        [id] => 729659027165160_729651713832558
        [likes] => Array (
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 729659027165160
                    )
                )
            [paging] => Array (
                [cursors] => Array (
                    [after] => NzI5NjU5MDI3MTY1MTYw
                    [before] => NzI5NjU5MDI3MTY1MTYw
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 729659027165160_718306454967084
        [likes] => Array (
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 1719747118259908
                    )
                )
            [paging] => Array (
                [cursors] => Array (
                    [after] => MTcxOTc0NzExODI1OTkwOA==
                    [before] => MTcxOTc0NzExODI1OTkwOA==
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 729659027165160_541135166017548
        [likes] => Array (
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 1162428970453842
                    )
                )
            [paging] => Array (
                [cursors] => Array (
                    [after] => MTE2MjQyODk3MDQ1Mzg0Mg==
                    [before] => MTE2MjQyODk3MDQ1Mzg0Mg==
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [message] => Panipaata leni prathivaadu philosophy cheppevade.... Wish Facebook introduce an unlike button soon!!!!
        [id] => 729659027165160_520677651396633
        [likes] => Array (
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 1162428970453842
                    )
                [1] => Array (
                    [id] => 806391372817118
                    )
                [2] => Array (
                    [id] => 928633297192567
                    )
                [3] => Array (
                    [id] => 824812004311172
                    )
                [4] => Array (
                    [id] => 10207344532684729
                    )
                [5] => Array (
                    [id] => 1188171664544003
                    )
                )
            [paging] => Array (
                [cursors] => Array (
                    [after] => MTE4ODE3MTY2NDU0NDAwMw==
                    [before] => MTE2MjQyODk3MDQ1Mzg0Mg==
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [4] => Array (
        [id] => 729659027165160_110578795739856
        [likes] => Array (
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 1162428970453842
                    )
                )
            [paging] => Array (
                [cursors] => Array (
                    [after] => MTE2MjQyODk3MDQ1Mzg0Mg==
                    [before] => MTE2MjQyO
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I am able to extract the id from the above array,but unable to extract the count of likes and message.

Comment: Please reformat the code snippet. I believe that once you do it, you will also see the solution to your problem.

Comment: Indeed what jso says, you can do so by putting the print_r between <pre></pre> tags.

Comment: Use this beautifier http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/ and see the array structure.

Comment: try `echo count($arr['data'][0]['likes']['data']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it iterates in your `array` and stores all `ids` and stores the `message`, the `likes Array` and the number of `likes` only if they exist (Supposing that your array is named `$myarray`):

```
$result = array();

foreach($myarray['data'] as $data){

    $item = array();

    $item['id'] = $data['id'];

    if( isset($data['message']) || isset($data['likes']) ){

        if(isset($data['message'])) $item['message'] = $data['message'];

        if(isset($data['likes'])) {

            $item['likes'] = array();

            foreach($data['likes']['data'] as $like){

                $item['likes'][] = $like['id'];

            }

            $item['countlikes'] = count( $data['likes']['data'] );

        }

    }

    $result[] = $item;

}

print_r($result);
```

With your example `Array` the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 729659027165160_729651713832558
            [message] => Hello
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 729659027165160
                )

            [countlikes] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 729659027165160_718306454967084
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1719747118259908
                )

            [countlikes] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 729659027165160_541135166017548
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1162428970453842
                )

            [countlikes] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 729659027165160_520677651396633
            [message] => Panipaata leni prathivaadu philosophy cheppevade.... Wish Facebook introduce an unlike button soon!!!!
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1162428970453842
                    [1] => 806391372817118
                    [2] => 928633297192567
                    [3] => 824812004311172
                    [4] => 10207344532684729
                    [5] => 1188171664544003
                )

            [countlikes] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 729659027165160_110578795739856
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1162428970453842
                )

            [countlikes] => 1
        )

)
```